# Как правильно дописать замыкание в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть написанный [кусок кода](https://repl.it/repls/BustlingElasticNumber):

Идея такая, в цикле итерировать массив, если найдено совпадение элементов от двух массивов, сформировать новый массив с порядковым индексом `n` и следующие элементы, которые итерируются в цикле, добавлять в ранее созданный массив `coorsinates[n]`, до следующего совпадения в цикле `if`.

Сейчас код выдает ошибку вида:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 25, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

По необходимости буду уточнять суть вопроса, если написал недостаточно внятно.

Comment: Ваша функция `mul` ничего не возвращает, попытка обратиться к ничему как к функции естественно приведёт к ошибке

Comment: И да, нехорошо изменять код без предупреждения. Ещё вчера код был совсем другим (@insolor имейте это в виду)

Comment: @John, в коде по ссылке указанная в вопросе ошибка не воспроизводится. Добавьте прямо в текст вопроса код, в котором данная проблема есть.